# trying to understand this random error i get //swift

Tags: swift, exc-bad-instruction

```
class Personnage {
    var vie = arc4random_uniform(10) + 1;
    var force = arc4random_uniform(8) + 1;
    var chance = arc4random_uniform(2);
    func attaquePar(joueur1:Personnage) ->String {
        var differenceForce = self.force - joueur1.force
        var coup = differenceForce + chance
        if coup >= self.vie {
            return "tu mas eu"
        } else if coup < self.vie {
            self.vie = self.vie - coup
            return "jai rien senti macaque \(self.vie)"
        } else {
            return "heu?"
        }
}
}
let toto = Personnage()
let cafard = Personnage()
toto.attaquePar(cafard)
```

Hi, I am having an error message at line 6. It works some times and other it does not. Here it is : Execution was interrupted, reason EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC I386_INVOP subcode=0x0).
I imagine that there is an invalid operation, but i don't undestant why i get this.

Comment: I assume this is on the line `var differenceForce = self.force - joueur1.force`? Could you check in the debugger that `self.force` and `joueur1.force` are what you expect them to be?

Comment: Thanks for your time Jim. I got the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type from `arc4random_uniform()` is `UInt32`, and computing 
the difference

```
var differenceForce = self.force - joueur1.force
```

will abort with a runtime exception the second operand is greater
that the first operand, i.e. the result is not representable as the (unsigned) `UInt32`. Unlike in some other
programming langages, results are not implicitly promoted to `Int`
or wrapped around.

A simple example:

```
let a = UInt32(3)
let b = UInt32(5)
let c = a - b //
```

A possible solution is to convert all
numbers to `Int`, so that differences can be computed without problems:

```
var vie = Int(arc4random_uniform(10)) + 1
var force = Int(arc4random_uniform(8)) + 1
// etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Martin. You were totally right.

Converting the variable type from UInt32 to Int was the solution.

```
var life = arc4random_uniform(10) 
var life = int(arc4random_uniform(10))
```

Comment: You are welcome, glad to help. – Note however that the preferred way of confirming a solution is to *accept* the answer (by clicking on the check mark). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for more information